# Update query is not working - need to look

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone tell where am I wrong in the query. The database in not updating irrespective of the value

```
<?php

// ================= UPDATE =========================
if ($_POST['SUBMIT']=='SUBMIT')
{
    $fixture_id = "$_GET[id]";
    $m_date = "$_POST[match_date]";
    $m_time = "$_POST[match_time]";
    $m_report = "$_POST[match_report]";
    $m_a_result = "$_POST[team_a_result]";
    $m_b_result = "$_POST[team_b_result]";

$updt = mysql_query("UPDATE `fixture` SET match_date='$m_date', match_time='$m_time', match_report='$m_report', match_a_result='$m_a_result', match_b_result='$m_b_result', status = 1 WHERE id = '$fixture_id'");

header("location:view_fixture.php?msg= You have inserted result successfully...");              

}
else
{
header("location:result_update.php?msg= Something went wrong...");              

}

// ================================================================================
?>
```

Comment: Lot of error ;- mixing `$_GET` an `$_POST`, using deprecated `mysql_*`,  no error reporting

Comment: Do you pass the id using query string?

Comment: Also query without any db connection

Comment: yes i am getting the id. when i print the values i am getting all values

Comment: stop using deprecated mysql_* functions  and start using pdo or mysqli

Comment: mysql_query almost die and vulnerable. Use myqli* or PDO. Besides, there are many errors in your codes.

Comment: not enough code to support the question

Comment: Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code and fix it.

Comment: @user3785303 did you tried really any answer or you are in a hurry to go to sleep?

Comment: people who are asking question are just lost there mind. i a deliting my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before executing this make sure your submit button have a string value of "SUBMIT"

Try this ..

```
<?php

    $fixture_id = $_GET[id];

if ($_POST['SUBMIT']=='SUBMIT')
{
    $m_date = $_POST['match_date'];
    $m_time = $_POST['match_time'];
    $m_report = $_POST['match_report'];
    $m_a_result = $_POST['team_a_result'];
    $m_b_result = $_POST['team_b_result'];

$updt = mysql_query("UPDATE `fixture` SET match_date= '$m_date', match_time='$m_time', match_report='$m_report', match_a_result='$m_a_result', match_b_result='$m_b_result', status = 1 WHERE id = '$fixture_id'");

header("location:view_fixture.php?msg= You have inserted result successfully...");              

}
else
{
header("location:result_update.php?msg= Something went wrong...");              

}


?>
```

**Please DO NOT USE mysql_* . It is now deprecated**

Comment: anirudhha where is db connection code?

Comment: also no validation that all values are coming also or not?

Comment: ok , editing my script wait a minute , plz :)

Comment: Great, please do that.